# Unable to use kartograph.py?

Tags: python, windows-7

I was able to download and install the Kartograph.py library. When I call it from the command line I am getting:

`kartograph is not an external command`

Usually from what I understand this is solved by setting the Path on Windows 7. I have tried everything I can think of and still get the same error.

For example if my path is:

`c:\python\katrograpy` I have tried to set it to `c:\python\katrograpy`, `c:\python\katrograpy\build`, `c:\python\katrograpy\bin` with no luck.

I am not a python programmer. I just need to use this to convert SHP files to SVG.

I am calling it this way. in `c:\python\katrography` I saved my `mapConfig.json` file and call it like this: `kartograph mapConfig.json`

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with kartograph but From their help http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.py/
In python I believe you should be calling it as `from kartograph import Kartograph
K = Kartograph()
K.generate(config, outfile='mymap.svg')`

Comment: @GISKid Im trying to call It from the command line. The page shows its here: `kartograph config.json -o mymap.svg`

Comment: How about setting up environment or system variables?

Answer (score 2):

- If you haven't installed using `python setup.py install` or `pip install kartograph.py` i.e. you just downloaded the zip file and unpacked it - the `kartograph` command is a python script (that can run as a Linux/Mac shell script). You can run it on Windows using `python <install dir>\bin\kartograph [args]`
- If you have installed using `python setup.py install` or `pip install
  kartograph.py`, a `kartograph.exe` will be built and copied to
  `<python install dir>\Scripts`. To run it, you can either add
  `<python install dir>\Scripts` to your PATH environment variable and
  call `kartograph [args]` or use the full path in your command line,
  i.e  `<python install dir>\Scripts\kartograph [args]`

On my system, I installed using `python setup.py install` so the command is available as:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\kartograph.exe
```